# is there equivalent of RecordSet.bookmark in DataSet C#

Tags: c#, vb6

I wanted to migrate a vb6 code in C#, my question is : if there is an equivalent of `RecordSet.bookmark` in DataSet C#

Equivalent VB6 code:
`pos = rsADO.Bookmark`

rsADO is ADODB.Recordset type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can obtain the same results by other means.

ADO Recordsets are what's called a "cursor". They have a "current record", and methods to set that current record to be at the top of the table, next, last and prior records.

DataSets (and most any other way to access structure data in C#) are not cursors. DataSets in particular are essentially arrays in memory, so there is no such thing as a "current record" in a DataSet, and there is no equivalent to Bookmark.

However, you can take a reference to a row object and save that. For example, something like:

```
DataRow row = myDataset.Tables[0].Rows[15];
```

That has the same effect as holding onto an ADO bookmark. Use the reference to act on that particular row.